# multi-dimensional sparse array in kotlin (jvm, js)?

Tags: java, kotlin, data-structures, jvm

I am searching for library implementing sparse multi-dimensional array for kotlin on jvm and js. There is [Sparse Array implementation in android.utils](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/util/SparseArray), but can it be used with JVM / JS ?
Or there is something in core library and I a m just missing it?

Comment: What properties are you looking for in this sparse array implementation? Usually a HashMap does the trick. Are you looking for more memory efficiency at the cost of speed?

Comment: it's for handling position of some entities in 3d space - basically [x][y][z] -> list of items at given position thing

Comment: Yes, but my question is about why not nested HashMaps? The implementation you linked to lists some advantages/disadvantages compared with HashMaps, so I was wondering which of these in particular was of interest to you. You could have a `Map<Int, Map<Int, Map<Int, List<Item>>>>`, which would basically do what you're looking for.

Comment: probably some dramatic over-engineering  ?

Comment: @Joffrey nested hashmaps may turn out to consume far more memory than a non-sparse array. In most cases, creating a dedicated key type holding three `int` values and using one flat `HashMap` would be more efficient.

Comment: @Holger yes, that would definitely be a better option than nesting maps, especially if we want to store a lot of keys. I was merely asking for the aspects that OP wanted to optimize with a sparse array as opposed to hashmaps in order to get a better picture of the question.

Comment: I need to effectively find closest neighbours In given range

Answer (score 0):

How about using a spatial index, such as quadtrees, R-trees, kd-trees?

I am not aware of any Kotlin library, but if you can use Java, have a look at [TinSpin](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes) index library.
Especially if the positions are integers and/or unique, I can suggest the [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) which has by default unique positions but can also be used as multimap (simply insert a map/list/set into any occupied position).

Disclaimer: Self-advertisement - I am the developer of TinSpin as well as the PH-Tree.